# how to make the nemey walk towards if in a certain range and stop befor my player UNITY5C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im making a diablo like game in Unity5 in c#. i wrote this code for the enemy:

```
public float viewRange;
public float attackRange;

bool casualBool;
GameObject playerObject;
NavMeshAgent enemyAgent;

void Start () {
    playerObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    enemyAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    viewRange = 6f;
    attackRange = 1.5f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) { Debug.Log(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerObject.transform.position)); }
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerObject.transform.position) > viewRange && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerObject.transform.position) > attackRange)
    {
        MoveToPlayer();
    }
    }

void MoveToPlayer()
{
        enemyAgent.SetDestination(playerObject.transform.position);
        transform.LookAt(playerObject.transform.position);
}
```

}

why does the enemy not stop in the given attackrange? he just continues to go into the player and then stops until the player quits the attack range. after that the enemy chases the player until he runs into him again.

Comment: You `enemyAgent.SetDestination()` to the player when the player is out of range, but shouldn't you then "halt" / stop the enemy when the player is in range? He might still have the player as his destination when he's in range. (i.e. in the `else` path of the `if(Vector3.Distance(..))` make the enemy stop with `enemyAgent.Stop()`?)

Comment: Thanks a lot it did work well :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you set the target range to your player's position. You could use colliders to determine the range, One collider to alert the enemy to head and another collider to determine the attack range.